# how to get data of check box list with text boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to get data from the textboxex that is related to the ckeckboxex in the checkboxlist .. 
in order to calculate the value of the selected box

this is my code :

```
foreach (ListItem item in listOthers.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);//textbox of selected checkbox
    }
}
lblSum.Text = sum.ToString();
```

What do I need to do to get the value of the textbox related to the checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, you have a CheckBoxList with a fixed size of 10 items and along with that 10 Textboxes (named TextBox1, TextBox2 and so on). The users marks some CheckBoxes and also enters a text into the corresponding Textboxes. You want to convert the Text of the Textboxes to an integer and calculate the sum of the marked entries.

You need to dynamically access the Textboxes by calling [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var index = 0;
foreach (ListItem item in listOthers.Items)
{
    index++; // Increase here as the Textbox numbers start at 1
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        var txt = FindControl("TextBox" + index.ToString()) as TextBox;
        if (txt != null)
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(txt.Text);  //text of selected Checkbox
    }
}
lblSum.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Please note that it is important to call FindControl on the container of the Textboxes. The call in the sample works if the Textboxes are located directly on the page. If they are located on a Panel named Panel1, you'd have to call:

```
var txt = Panel1.Findcontrol("TextBox" + index.ToString()) as Textbox;
```

An alternative to using a CheckBoxList that is prepared for variable sizes by design and having a fixed list of 10 TextBoxes next to it, would be to create a Repeater with a CheckBox and a TextBox in its ItemTemplate. Downsize is that you'd have to create some DTOs for DataBinding and also had to use some more dynamic control resolution (both for the CheckBox and the TextBox ).

Comment: thanks for the reply , but what i need is to get the value inside a text-box that is corresponding to the checkbox .. only when its checked 

so the user select a check box from its list and i have to get values from a another list of corresponding textboxes

Comment: @user3162254: I understand. How do the Textboxes correspond to the items in the CheckBoxList? Are they named after a certain pattern? Do you create them dynamically? Is the number of items in the CheckBoxList fixed?

Comment: each one of the check-boxes has text-box beside it , in order to get the text-box content if the correspond check-box is selected , 10 check-boxes list and 10 text-boxes(fixed)